# What is the importance of Banach space in the theory of semigroups of linear operators?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, banach-spaces, semigroup-of-operators

Pazy's book defines semigroups as follows. Let $X$ be a Banach space. A one parameter family $T(t)$, $0< t < \infty$, of bounded linear operators from $X$ into $X$ is a semigroup of
bounded linear operators on $X$ if

(i) $T(0) = I$, ($I$ is the identity operator on $X$).

(ii) $T(t + s) = T(t)T(s)$ for every $t, s \geq 0$ (the semigroup property).

What is the importance of $X$ Banach space in the theory of semigroups of linear operators? Does anything break if I require that $X$ just be a complete metric space?

Comment: You can write down whatever definitions you want, but it's a lot harder to say things about maps on metric spaces and a lot easier to say things about linear maps on Banach spaces. One of the only things we really know how to do in mathematics is linear algebra so we try to reduce everything else to linear algebra whenever possible.

Comment: Try doing some proofs of the following statements in the text involving semigroups without being able to add and you will understand pretty quickly

Comment: There is no such thing as linear operators unless you're working with a linear space, and no such thing as bounded linear operators unless you're working with a normed linear space.  Throw in completeness, and you have a Banach space.